# What is the overhead for calling JPA.withTransaction() in Play! 2.x

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, playframework-2.0

So, finding how to use JPA in play has been a bit of a headache, but I recently found that you can do a transaction outside of a `@Transactional` controller method by using `JPA.withTransaction()`.  I assume this doesn't come without costs, though. I.e.:

```
JPA.withTransaction( () -> {
    ...do some db updates...
}
```

When using this method, what exactly happens?  Is there another `EntityManager` created every time you call it, or is an existing one brought in?  Is it just a transaction that's created?  Just trying to get an idea of what the overhead is for using this.

Bonus question: If I'm using this on many concurrently running threads, is there a better way for them all to get at some global transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that paly framerwork has differents kind to manage EntityManager and connections: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA

In case you are using

```
JPA.withTransaction( () -> {
    ...do some db updates...
}
```

play framework create a new Entity Manager with a single transaction that perform the contents tha to write insite.

Other approach can be the use of @Transactional into an action of a controller. In this way the transaction is completely managed by the framework and is related to the http request that is on going.